# How to transform an array into matrix by grouping in typescript

Tags: typescript, group-by, ngfor

How can I transform the following array or objects into a new array or objects where each key element has the key element from the grouping and a inner collection witht the elements from the grouping.

i.e I want to turn this array

```
[
 { "type": "1", "name": "a", "age": "10" },
 { "type": "1", "name": "b", "age": "11" },
 { "type": "2", "name": "c", "age": "12" }
]
```

into

```
[
 { "key": "1", "elements": [{"name": "a", "age": "10"},
                         {"name": "b", "age": "11"}]},
 { "key": "2", "elements": [{"name": "c", "age": "12"}]}
]
```

Is this possible and if so how?

I also want to bind this new object twice to to an *ngFor so the inner element needs to be an array or can I do that in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

It's a basic function, most utility libs have. [Here](https://github.com/TylorS/typed/tree/master/packages/list#groupbykeys-extends-string-af-arity1a-keys-list-lista-readonlyrecordkeys-lista) is an example of it, it's very small and modular, properly typed and shows source.